# Why is scan.nextLine() skips in my Java Program?

Tags: java

I could not find out the reason why this code skips scan.nextLine()... 
I put comment on that line... when I go the debugger and skip over it doesnt allow me to enter the String data..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int x =0, y=0;
        char path[][];

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        x = scan.nextInt();
        y = scan.nextInt();

        path = new char[x][y];
        String[] input = new String[y];



        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){

            input[i] = scan.nextLine(); // this line is skipped...

            for(int yIndex = 0; yIndex < input.length; yIndex++){
                path[i][yIndex] = input[i].charAt(yIndex);
            }
        }



    }
```

Comment: What is the input? If `x` is less than or equal to zero, this is the correct inpterpretation.

Comment: The `Scanner` simply reads the first line `4 5` but doesn't automatically read the next line. You need to insert a `scan.nextLine()` before the `for` loop.

Comment: Hi thanks, I had added it before I post but adding scan.nextLine while not actually scanning somehow doesnt make sense to me.. is this some kind of bug in Java?

Comment: *" ... is this some kind of bug in Java"* - Nope.  It works this way by design.  If `nextInt()` consumed the characters in the case when they weren't a valid integer, you wouldn't have any way to reparse them as something else.